# Firebase deploy error missing API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Im getting that error when I try make my first deploy on Firebase, someone knows how I can solve that?

```
i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
+  database: rules syntax is valid
i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
+  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
+  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
!  functions: missing necessary APIs. Enabling now...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...

Error: Timed out waiting for APIs to enable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This issue is related to an [ongoing incident](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17026) involving project creation. Keep an eye on the status page for resolution.